# C - Print an array filled with Unicode-Symbols

Tags: c, arrays, unicode, char, printf

I want to print an array(/string), which is filled with unicode (and normal) symbols , for example squares.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char array[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        array[i]='\u25A1';
    }
    array[4]='A';
    printf("%s", array);
    return 0;
}
```

It just prints " ííííA◊".
Why doesn't it print the squares, and how to fix it?

According to fileformat.info the square's

C/C++/Java source code  is  "\u25A0"

i also tried the square's

UTF-8 (hex), which is "0xE2 0x96 0xA0 (e296a0)"

Neither work.

Answer (score 2):

`array[i] = '\u25A1'` will not compile correctly in C. You should at least get a compiler warning.

`'\u25A1'` is of type `char16_t` (two bytes per character), it is not relevant here.

`\u` can be used as a [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) in a string literal, to represent Unicode code points below `0x10000`. Example:

```
strcpy(array, u8"\u25A0");
printf(array);
```

> ```
> Output: ■
> ```

Note that `u8"\u25A0"` is stored as 4 bytes (`0xE2, 0x96, 0xA0` + null-character) based on UTF8 conversion. It can also be printed as follow (if the console supports UTF8 output):

```
strcpy(array, "\xE2\x96\xA0");
printf(array);
```

> ```
> Output: ■
> ```

Moreover the string should be null-terminated, the last character in the string should be zero.

To store UTF8 in bytes, you can assign values as follows:

```
array[0] = 0xE2;
array[1] = 0x96;
array[2] = 0xA0;
array[3] = '\0';
```

If your development environment supports it you can also declare

```
char array[] = u8"■";
```

Comment: Thanks @chux. I cleaned up the answer a bit.

Comment: Other minor: "u8"\u25A0" is turned in to 3 bytes" --> 4 bytes  (3 + \0) as string literals always append a null character.

Comment: it just prints "öüä" for everything you said  :/

Comment: It depends on your operating system, the version of your operating system, and if the console supports UTF8. I don't know anything about your environment you are using.

Comment: @flogg1: maybe you should specify your OS in your question. The Windows console, for example, may need some forced coercing before it does something as wildly far-fetched as defaulting to UTF8...

Comment: yea, I got windows.